# リストの要素と内容表示について

Tags: java

JAVAのプログラム①と②でリストに要素（インデックス）とランダムに生成した値を入れて表示したのですが、③のようになり思うような表示が出ません。本当は④のようにしたいのですが・・・①、②のどこに、どのような修正が必要でしょうか。

①MyData クラスは，データの生成番号と値を格納する

```java
public class MyData {
    public int index;   
    public double data; 
    //コントラクタ
    public MyData(int index, double data){
    }
}
```

②ランダムに生成された 10 個の値を List に格納、表示

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Randomprintln {
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
         List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<>();          
         for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {       
             MyData d = new MyData(i, Math.random());      
             list.add(d);
          } 
      System.out.println(list);
     } 
}
```

③上記実行時のコンソールの表示結果

```
[pro4202042.MyData@15db9742, pro4202042.MyData@6d06d69c, pro4202042.MyData@7852e922, pro4202042.MyData@4e25154f, pro4202042.MyData@70dea4e, pro4202042.MyData@5c647e05, pro4202042.MyData@33909752, pro4202042.MyData@55f96302, pro4202042.MyData@3d4eac69, pro4202042.MyData@42a57993]
```

④本当は表示させたい結果のイメージ

```
[0]=乱数
[1]=乱数
[2]=乱数
:
:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コンストラクタに処理が無いので

```java
public MyData(int index, double data){
}
```

引数の`index`も`data`も無視されます（フィールド変数`index`、`data`には値が設定されません）。まずはそれを以下のように修正する必要があります。

```java
public MyData(int index, double data){
    this.index = index;
    this.data = data;
}
```

それから、`System.out.println(list);`で値を表示したいのであれば、`MyData`に`toString()`を実装する必要があります。

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("[%d]=%f",index, data);
}
```

ただし、これだと「④本当は表示させたい結果のイメージ」とは若干異なる出力になりますので、必要に応じて実装を修正して下さい（ループ内で`System.out.println()`するとか）。

Answer (score 1):

以下は [java.ArrayList.forEach()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) を使う場合です。

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class MyData {
  public int index;
  public double data;

  //コントラクタ
  public MyData(int index, double data){
    this.index = index;
    this.data = data;
  }
}

public class Randomprint {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
      list.add(new MyData(i, Math.random()));
    }
    list.forEach(
      d -> System.out.printf("[%d]=%.5f\n", d.index, d.data));
  }
}

=>
$ javac -Xlint:unchecked Randomprint.java
$ java Randomprint
[0]=0.54200
[1]=0.94190
[2]=0.13860
[3]=0.90671
[4]=0.45146
[5]=0.92236
[6]=0.22481
[7]=0.79221
[8]=0.46996
[9]=0.65752
```